# Printing sympy input function

Tags: python, sympy

I have been experimenting with sympy, and I have been searching for a way to print the input of my math function, not just the result.

For example, if I type

```
integrate(x**2 + x + 1, x)
```

I get: [image: formula]

though I would like a way to output something like to this: [image: formula]

Is this possible? If so how would it be implemented?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This.

```
a = Integral(x**2 + x + 1, x)
Eq(a,a.doit())
```

Comment: That worked perfektly for Integrals :D Thanks. Now what if I would like to do the same thing, but for something more basic, such as 5+4, so i get. 5+4=9?

Comment: I am not sure about symbol-less equation like 5 + 4 = 9. But if you are looking for some symbolic equation like x + 4 = 9. Eq will work for it.    Eq(x+4,9)

Comment: @user3120921: `sym.S('5+4', evaluate=False)` returns a `sympy.core.add.Add` object.